# How to upload text as a text file in form with input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a text field which can contain some text. I have a form with input type file in my page (Cannot change this form). When submit button (linked with text field and not the form) is clicked, what I want is that the text should be stored in some file and this file be uploaded through the form automatically.

More accurately, I am not concerned with storing text in file, but with actually having the text uploaded through the form (without having to change the form structure). This is the form:

```
<form action=submit.cgi enctype='multipart/form-data' method=POST
      onSubmit="checkIT(this.form)">
<input type=hidden name=asgn value=5>
<input type=hidden name=catno value=1>
Assignment-5<br>
Individual submission: <br>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>txt (Optional, Extension: txt):
    <td valign=top><input type=file name="i1">
    <input type=hidden name="junk-i1" value="junk-i1"><br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>txt (Optional, Extension: txt):
    <td valign=top><input type=file name="i2">
    <input type=hidden name="junk-i2" value="junk-i2"><br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>txt (Optional, Extension: txt):
    <td valign=top><input type=file name="i3">
    <input type=hidden name="junk-i3" value="junk-i3"><br>
</tr>
</table>
<br>    <p>
<input type=submit name=isub value=Submit onClick="checkIT2(this.form)">
<input type=hidden name=junk1 value="junk1">
<input type=hidden name=junk2 value="junk2">
</form>
```

Comment: Is the question not clear?

Comment: "I have a text field which can contain some text." — There is no text field in the code in your question.

Comment: "I am not concerned with storing text in file" — Why spend half a paragraph asking about that then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is - for security reasons you `CANNOT` set a file with `javascript` to an `input type file` element. It is prohibited by browsers. So this cannot be possible the way you wanted. But you can mock the request to the same address using `CURL`.

So the steps should be:

- from your own form get the input text
- write that input text as text file
- mock the request of the given form with CURL including the field names of the given form [*for more info: http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/*]